# django admin not recognized after enabling django-social-auth backends

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have used django-social-auth in my project to sign in using facebook but then I couldn't login to django admin page even after logout from facebook.

I thought I forgot my password and tried to change it from shell got:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
<QuerySet []>
```

Here's my setting.py file:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'portfolio',
    ]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # For Facebook Authentication
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    # Default Django Auth Backends
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )


TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',

             # Setting of Template Context Processors for Social Auth
            'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
            'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect', 
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Personal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cover = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And I have a form.py file:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from . import models as m

class PersoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = m.Personal
        fields = ['name', 'status', 'address', 'email', 'phone', 'cover']
```

I know I can create a new superuser but I want to understand why this is happening and how can I use both the django-admin and django-social-auth?

I appreciate some clarification here, I am new to django framework.

Comment: Do you have `AUTH_USER_MODEL` set? Does `User.objects.all()` return the admin user amongst others?

Comment: If you don't have a custom user model, then I doubt your admin user actually exists

Comment: @MosesKoledoye `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is not set and `User.objects.all()` shows only the facebook user. I am reading about it now.

Comment: Even if I was login/out from it all the time from localhost:8000/admin and it was working before using django-social-auth?

Comment: Some wild guesses that I would consider for debugging - perhaps your shell isn't in the same environment as your project? I.e. your project is in virtualenv1 and you opened the shell in virtualenv2 or global environment?  

Could it be that you've switched your databases (pretty simple with sqlite)?  

Are you sure that you haven't overridden the default user model with one of your own? Perhaps show us the content of `portfolio/models.py`?

Comment: I don't think so, I work in one virtualenv, and my model is pretty simple doesn't include the user model. I edited my post with the content of models.py

Comment: @makaveli I don't know if that's relevant, but I remove the db.sqlite3 quite often and run `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

Comment: Every time you remove the db.sqlite3 file, you remove your whole database with all your users and whatnot. In local development, db.sqlite3 is your (SQLite) database that stores all the data and you cannot possibly in any way log in without the user data being in the database. Create a new superuser and continue experimenting. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you sir, I am sorry for wasting your time guys. There's a lot i need to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `python manage.py createsuperuser` ? It looks like you have no super user at all. How did you login into `admin` ?

Comment: I created a superuser using the command above, I entered a username instead of admin and a password. I registered my model in myapp/admin.py and was managing the data from the django admin page.